# Cannot load 64-bit SWT libraries on 32-bit JVM (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android-studio

При попытке запустить через консоль uiautomatorviewer получаю следующую ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 64-bit SWT libraries on 32-bit JVM
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.createShell(Window.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:430)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:790)
    at com.android.uiautomator.UiAutomatorViewer.main(UiAutomatorViewer.java:78)
```

Android Studio 64бит, JAVA_HOME ведет к 64бит java, и при проверке на `java -version` как из корневого каталога, так и из папки, хранящей `.bat` файл указывается 64бит:

```
java version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13, mixed mode)
```

Мне удалось определить, что действительно, происходит попытка запустить 32bit JVM. При переименовании этой папки консоль предлагает установить JAVA_HOME, т.к. подходящей версии java не найдено.

Собственно вопрос в том, откуда еще может браться этот ложный путь, если правильный прописан в переменных, определяется через `java -version` и даже в настройках AndroidStudio прописан.

Возможно, у вас есть соображения на этот счет?

Comment: Посмотрите на реестр Windows, запускаете regedit и смотрите раздел `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->Software->JavaSoft->Java Runtime Environment` - там еще прописываются настройки

Comment: Там тоже все указано правильно

Answer (score 0):

Я решил эту проблему , скачав заново swf.jar по адресу http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.5.1-200909170800/index.php#SWT

Версия которую я использовал (скачивал) Windows (x86_64)(Supported Versions)(http)5.5 MB swt-3.5.1-win32-win32-x86_64.zip

Необходимо узнать где у вас храниться swf.jar, распаковать скачанный архив и заменить старый файл в директории на новый (тот что скачали)

Не забудьте прописать в переменных среды, переменную,  ANDROID_SWF в которой параметром будет путь к папке с файлом swf.jar

Comment: Перенёс из комментария. На Stackoverflow пишите по-английски, но здесь сайт Stackoverflow на русском - и мы общаемся на русском языке.